# Discord.js send message if have a role

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to send dm to anyone who has the role of "xxx" when the bot starts. Can you help me?

Comment: Cant help you unless you show what you've tried first

Comment: Please, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [make a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You need to provide enough information about what you already tried. Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  const list = client.guilds.get("guild ID");
  list.members.forEach(member => {
     if (member.roles.some(role => role.name === 'Your role')) {
        member.send('Your message')
     }
  });  
});
```

The way it works is when the bot is ready it will check each member if they have the specified role and if they do then the bot will send it a DM.

A tip, when asking questions like this provide more information on what the problem is, what you've tried and you're current code.